# Access all keys including lists in JSON using Python

Tags: python, json, dictionary, recursion, nested

I would like to access all the keys including within lists in a JSON document and modify them.

I have the following code, but this just prints the top level keys:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import json

file = 'example.json'
f = open(file)
data = json.load(f)

for key, value in data.items():
        print(key)
```

Thus, for the JSON document:

```
{
"a":1,
"b":2,
"c":[
     {
     "d":4,
     "e":5,
     "f":{
         "g":6
         }
     }
    ]
}
```

I just get the output:

```
a
b
c
```

whereas I want to access and amend all the keys, namely:

```
a
b
c
d
e
f
g
```

Note that `c` is a list, which hides `d e f g`.

Comment: You need a recursive approach here.

Answer (score 3):

You will need some sort of recursion to traverse the data:

```
def nested_keys(obj):
    if isinstance(obj, dict):
        for k, v in obj.items():
            yield k
            yield from nested_keys(v)
    elif isinstance(obj, list):
        for sub in obj:
            yield from nested_keys(sub)

>>> [*nested_keys(data)]
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
```

To rename keys:

```
def rename_keys(obj, mapping):
    if isinstance(obj, dict):
        return {mapping[k]: rename_keys(v, mapping) for k, v in obj.items()}
    if isinstance(obj, list):
        return [rename_keys(sub, mapping) for sub in obj]
    return obj

rename_keys(data, dict("a1 b2 c3 d4 e5 f6 g6".split()))
# {'1': 1, '2': 2, '3': [{'4': 4, '5': 5, '6': {'6': 6}}]}
```

Comment: Plus one - problem is that you possibly cannot do anything with the nested keys (one is not able to get the value with the key names alone, that is).

Comment: Thanks @user2390182, that prints out all the keys. How would I change the key names? I have tried defining a new global dictionary ```data2 = { }``` and adding ```data2[k + '0'] = obj[k]``` after the ```for k, v in obj.items:``` line, but the result is ```data2 = {'a0': 1, 'b0': 2, 'c0': [{'d': 4, 'e': 5, 'f': {'g': 6}}], 'd0': 4, 'e0': 5, 'f0': {'g': 6}, 'g0': 6}```. That is, the new keys have been added to the list, but the old keys have not been deleted.

Comment: Can you provide some hints with regard to the logic of the renaming

Comment: I have a Python dictionary with old key names and new key names. Ideally I want to replace the key names in situ, but I could also create a new JSON document from the existing JSON document.

Comment: Added an example to create a new dict with keys replaced by their substitute taken from a mapping.

Comment: Thanks @user2390182, that's great. The only issue with the mapping/dictionary is that I want the existing key to remain if it is not present, e.g. if I call ```rename_keys(data, dict("a1 b2 c3 d4 e5 f6".split()))```. That is, without ```g6```, I want to get ```{'1': 1, '2': 2, '3': [{'4': 4, '5': 5, '6': {'g': 6}}]}```

Comment: Hi @user2390182, What does the colon (```:```) mean in ```mapping[k]: rename_keys(v, mapping)```? How would I unwrap this into multiple lines, so I can check if a key exists?

Comment: To answer my own questions, the colon (```:```) in the previous comment is a dictionary comprehension, and using ```mapping.get(k,k):``` in place of ```mapping[k]:``` returns the value of k or k if it does not exist in the dictionary.